# When does a morphism $f:X \to C$ from a group extension $X \twoheadrightarrow G$ factor through $G$?

Tags: group-theory, commutative-algebra, finite-groups, abelian-groups, group-extensions

All the letters denote abelian groups (all finite except for $C$). Let $Y$ be an extension of $G$ by $B$ and let $f: Y \to C$ be a group homomorphism. Now, I want to find the maximal $G$-subextension $X \subseteq Y$ by $A \subseteq B$, s.t. there is a map $\tilde{f}:G \to C$ with $f\circ \iota = \tilde{f} \circ \pi_X$, where $\pi_X:X \to G$ is the projection of $X$ to $G$ and $\iota$ denotes the inclusion of $X$ in $Y$. Is this a known problem? If so, where can I find something about it? Of course, I am basically interested in existence and uniqueness statements..

Comment: Of course we want to define $\overline{f}(g)=f(x)$ when $\pi_X(x)=g$. The choice of $x$ is unique up to multiplying by an element of $\ker\pi_X$. Thus we need $\ker \pi_X\subseteq\ker f|_X$. This is in fact necessary and sufficient. As long as there is at least one subgroup $X\leq Y$ with this property, there will be a maximal one by Zorn's Lemma, and it will necessarily contain $B$. I don't know results about uniqueness of the maximal one.